# How augur.io uniquely recognise device?

Tags: javascript, web, uniqueidentifier, fingerprinting

[Augur](https://www.augur.io/#deviceFeatures) recognize device laptop/pc/tablet a uniquely by assigning a unique id (augur.json.consumer.UID). 
Open [Augur](https://www.augur.io/#deviceFeatures) and type `augur.json.consumer.UID` in browser console.

I try opening in different browsers, unique id remains same for each browser in the same device.
I know about fingerprinting, but fingerprinting is browser based.

How it uniquely recognise the device?

It is unable to give unique id in some browser like safari in mac.

Comment: They probably have an algorithm that analyzes things like screen resolution, operating system, etc. and uses all the info that's available to a browser to create a unique ID. You can see all a browser knows about you here: http://webkay.robinlinus.com

Comment: But it gives same unique id for different browser.

Comment: @PatrickHund what you are saying is like browser fingerprinting

Comment: Well, their technology can only analyze the information that is available to the browser. But things like screen resolution and OS will be the same with every browser. My guess is they use that info that is the same in every browser to create a device fingerprint.

Answer (score 0):

They are using something called cross browser fingerprinting, idea is webgl rendering only uses os + hardware if you render without loss format (like png).